# C# encryption key discussion

Tags: c#, encryption

I am writing a .net application and want to use a supper strong encryption key by using the unicode characters to make it hard for the hackers to hack the code. The encryption key would be any characters from the http://www.unicode.org. 
For example my encryption key could லูᇉޒۻڃxxxxxxxxxxxx + couple hundred characters which is very difficult for the computer to predict my code. I think the unicode has more than 95,000 characters.

I am wondering if there is any data corruption because of these complex characters. Of course I have to check the decrypt data to make sure the code can decrypt before I save the information to the database. I have tested my code for more than 10 millions times to see how reliable and it run pretty good.

Any thoughts guys?

Comment: You shouldn't ever use an encryption key that is real text. You should use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` to derive a key from text, salt it, and use many iterations.

Comment: Why not just use one of the known encryption methods and be done?

Comment: If you're using an encryption key based on unicode, you're essentially making a key with n * sizeof(unicode character), where n is the length of your unicode string. Just stick with bytes, like vcsjones recommended.

Comment: Rfc2898DeriveBytes  sound pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is very very difficult to do. More likely than not, your approach will be very insecure.

The strength of an algorithm is more than just a key size. I'd wager that DES with a 56-bit key is more "secure" than probably any home made cipher.

The AES process was a multiple year effort of every cryptographer in the world, multiple government agencies, support from Microsoft, RSA (among others), various open source projects, and millions of dollars. Even after all that, we still find new attacks against AES.

What are your requirements? You should use established protocols and algorims. If you say what your trying to do, we can give better advice.

Comment: XOR is stronger than most hand rolled ciphers ;P

Comment: i am  doing so i can store customer data on the share hosting account. Using  TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() and MD5CryptoServiceProvider()